# ArrayAdapter passed to setAdapter method

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm new to android. I have a MainActivity which extends from ActionBarActivity and implements a NavigationdrawerFragment. I initialize an ArrayList in the MainActivity and I want to pass that array to the NavigationDrawerFragment to populate my drawerlayout. I can't do it, because the setAdapter method is called inside the NavigationdrawerFragment.java instead of MainActivity.java. I don't get any idea of how to work this process, any solutions?

Comment: Can we see some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a factory method in your fragment (sample assumes your ArrayList is of String objects):

```
public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String ARG_KEY_INIT_DATA = "init_data";

    public static NavigationDrawerFragment createInstance(ArrayList initData) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putStringArrayList(ARG_KEY_INIT_DATA, initData);
        NavigationDrawerFragment frag = new NavigationDrawerFragment();
        frag.setArguments(args);
        return frag;
    }
    ...
}
```

Then in the `Fragment`'s `onCreate()` method you can extract the argument data and set it in your adapter as needed.